# Delphi and Windows Logon Events

Tags: delphi, windows-services, delphi-2010

I want to know how to receive windows logon and logoff events inside a delphi windows service.
The service itself is already built, now I want to show a systray icon that opens a settings/logs window. To show that icon I need to know if a user has logged in...

I have seen some info regarding "System Event Notification Service" for c#, but there is very little info on delphi.

Comment: I trust you understand that the notification icon will not be part of the service process. It needs a separate desktop process.

Comment: @Ken Your supposed duplicate is a .net question

Comment: Ken White, I saw that post, but since the dev language was different...
David Hefferman, I was trying to avoid that. I have seen c# tutorials on how to do this in 1 process, so I wanted to know if it was possible to do in delphi. But if it is the only way...

Comment: You can't do it in one process in any language. Services run in session 0 and cannot show notification icons (or indeed any UI) on an interactive desktop.

Comment: Well, thank you for the advice. I'll look into other possibilities.

Comment: @David: You're right; it is. Another note to self: No close votes before the coffee fully kicks in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since user sessions are based on RDS ([Remote Desktop Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - former Terminal Services) technology you can try [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[WTSRegisterSessionNotificationEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs. [They give you information about various events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like:

- WTS_SESSION_LOGON
- WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF
- WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT
- WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT
- WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT
- WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT etc.

Based on the event you can find user's session ID. Then you can start a process in this specific session (i.e. [inject a program to a specific RDS session](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/20/how-to-launch-a-process-in-a-terminal-session/)). For example you can start a process in user's session that shows your icon(s). This process can communicate with your service via named pipes, memory mapped files etc.

Personally I use these events to stop GUI intensive work when a user disconnects from a session (i.e. stop updating labels, listboxes, memos etc.)

** These APIs require to have a window that receives notifications. [In a service you need to create a hidden one with a message loop (another topic)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6902074/1022219)