# How to capture logoff cancelled in windows server 2003

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, delphi

I'm working on a terminal services based system running on windows 2003. It consists of a desktop replacement application from which the user starts programs. It also has a logoff-button. When the user logs off two things must happen. First off, he is logged out of windows. Then a stored procedure is called cleaning up the users database state. This almost works fine, but for one situation, and that is when the user cancels the logoff event. Typical scenario: 
1- User logs in, starts MS Word, edits the document, does not save. 
2 - The user then presses the logoff button. 
3- MS Word reacts to this asking the user to save his changes. 
4 - The user presses cancel.

At this point the desktop application might already have called the stored procedure cleaning up the database state. How do I catch this behaviour in the desktop application? Is there a message saying that the end session operation was cancelled?

Does my question make sense at all?

Oh, all of the applications are written in Delphi 7, but I work in C, C++ and C# as well, so answers in those languages are appreciated as well.

Comment: are you allowed to run a service on that machine? ... also, have you tried to kick off your stored procedure with a grouppolicy based logoff script?

Comment: I think you should instead try to detect actual logoff and assume canceled otherwise: The Word-cancel occurs when a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message is sent to Word; If the logoff is canceled, the system will never send a `WM_ENDSESSION` message.

Comment: @Medinoc: The MSDN documentation states: "When an application returns TRUE for WM_QUERYENDSESSION, it receives the WM_ENDSESSION message and it is terminated, regardless of how the other applications respond to the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message." That implies that my desktop replacement app will receive WM_ENDSESSION even if it is cancelled in word.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: Yes, I can implement and run services on the machine. Running a logoff script might not be a bad idea. That doesn't solve the problem though, since I still need the desktop replacement up and running if the user cancels the log out process through, for instance, word.

Comment: in that case i'd either choose to start the cleanup with the logoff script, or run a service that get's a hold on the process of your shell and listens for the termination of the shell (as far as i know the shell is the last process that will be killed on session end ...)

Comment: I actually have no shell process in the common sense. My desktop replacement application is started as the first application. This is configured in Citrix, which is the terminal services solution we have. The user is not allowed to execute explorer.exe. So as I figure it, I need my desktop replacement to respond to the ENDSESSION message last and only if no other applications have responded false to the QUERYENDSESSION message.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: So if the shell is the last process to be killed on session end, does that mean that it survives if the session ending is cancelled?

Comment: well ... i don't know how this behaves with citrix ... but on a windows terminal server i'd change the users shell in the registry and try ... the last time i saw something like this was years ago...

Answer (score 0):

If your user state logic is inside your shell replacement then think of Application redesign: Decouple Custom Shell from Session management.

For example: Move your User state logic in a service. Within this service register for RDS Notifications: WTS_SESSION_LOGON/WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF.

I think WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF is sent *only* when actual logoff occurs i.e. if the user clicks Cancel button in Word then Windows would know that the user hasn't logged off actually and OS would not send WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF (this is untested, but sounds logical).

This way you don't deal with WM_ENDSESSION/WM_QUERYENDSESSION stuff.

[Recently I wrote some guidance on RDS notifications topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970898/1022219)

Comment: That still leaves the problem of keeping my desktop replacement if a user initiates a logoff which is cancelled. The replacement isn't a proper shell, but just a graphical interface which gets started as the first application in Citrix.